# C# array into MWarray Matlab

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have an MxNx3 matrix and i want to transfer it into matlab using `MWArray`.
Here is my code, however there is no CTOR for that.
Is there any way to do it?

```
RGBImage image = _currentImage as RGBImage;

int height = image.Height;
int width = image.Width;

//transform the 1D array of byte into MxNx3 matrix 
byte[, ,] rgbByteImage = new byte[3, height, width];
if (image[0].Bpp > 16)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0, k = 0; k < width; j = j + 3, k++)
        {
            rgbByteImage[0, i, k] = image[0].Data[i * width + j]; 
            rgbByteImage[1, i, k] = image[0].Data[i * width + j + 1]; 
            rgbByteImage[2, i, k] = image[0].Data[i * width + j + 2 ]; 
        }
    }
}

MWNumericArray tempArr = new MWNumericArray(rgbByteImage);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
RGBImage image = _currentImage as RGBImage;

int height = image.Height;
int width = image.Width;

//transform the 1D array of byte into MxNx3 matrix 

byte[ , , ] RGBByteImage = new byte[3,height, width];

if (image[0].Bpp > 16)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0, k = 0; k < width; j = j + 3, k++)
        {
            RGBByteImage[0, i, k] = image[0].Data[3 * i * width + j];
            RGBByteImage[1, i, k] = image[0].Data[3 * i * width + j + 1];
            RGBByteImage[2, i, k] = image[0].Data[3 * i * width + j + 2]; 
        }
    }
}

MWNumericArray matrix = null;
matrix = new MWNumericArray(MWArrayComplexity.Real, MWNumericType.Int8, 3,height, width);
matrix = RGBByteImage;
```

This is what I have found.

There is also a nice tutorial here 
http://domoreinlesstime.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/access-matlab-from-c/

Please notice that you have the correct refernce to the MWArray.dll file (x64 or x86). I have wasted a day or so on that.